# How do I fix my Vite.ts/React website in Github Pages showing a blank white page?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, git, github-pages, vite

This is my first time creating a React app throught Vite. As stated in the title, when I open the link a blank white page appears. Also, I am using TypeScript for this project as opposed to JavaScript. Don't know if this is a reason for my issue.

This project I made is a hangman project I used to learn from Youtube [(YouTube Link Here)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-ONUyenGnWw&t=201s&ab_channel=WebDevSimplified). Here is a link to my Github repository too --> [The Github Repo](https://github.com/chris-azuaje/hangman). What do I need to do to get the GitHub Pages link to work?

I tried adding some configurations, using Git commands in the terminal, and a few other things. But many of these seem to be geared towards JavaScript files and not TypeScript.

Comment: Did you build the project? Does anything show up in the browser console when visiting the page?

Comment: @LW001 yes, the project is built and the link above is the link to my Github which has all the files. And nothing shows up in the browser, just a blank white screen.

Comment: I meant in the console (usually F12) - Looking at your page it tries serving me some JSX files that don't exist which probably means something with GitHub Pages is off. I don't have a way of testing it but [this](https://github.com/gitname/react-gh-pages) looks like some sane instructions on how to deploy a React app to GitHub Pages. It mentions something about a gh-pages branch which you don't seem to have?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

#### 1. Set the correct base in vite.config.js:

```js
export default defineConfig({
  // ...
  base: "/hangman/",
  // ...
})
```

Note: If your repository is at `https://github.com/<USERNAME>/<REPO>`, then set base to `/<REPO>/`.

#### 2. Create a workflow for Github Pages:

In order to do so, you can create a file `/.github/workflows/main.yml` and the following content: https://github.com/luis-sandbox/hangman/blob/e6905e9dfc670afe675e033d78e844b4e4deec30/.github/workflows/main.yml

#### 3. Wait a few seconds for the app to be build

You can see the status in `<repoURL>/actions/`

---

- Source: https://vitejs.dev/guide/static-deploy.html#github-pages
- Working example:

  - repo: https://github.com/luis-sandbox/hangman
  - status: https://github.com/luis-sandbox/hangman/actions/
  - deployed url: https://luis-sandbox.github.io/hangman/